# My code is not detecting when an object touches my trigger in unity

Tags: c#, 2d

I am trying to have my code get when an object enters or exits a trigger, and then add or remove it from a list based on which it did (enter or exit). the gameobject the code is on had a circle collider set to is trigger being true, and all gameobjects passing through the trigger have a boxcollider2d attached to it. the color change is just for visual indicator that it is working

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TowerTargeting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> targets = new List<GameObject>();

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(targets.Count != 0)
        {
            targets[0].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.blue;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        Debug.Log("Enemy Found");
        targets.Add(col.gameObject);
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        Debug.Log("Enemy Lost");
        targets.Remove(col.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check that the colliders of the objects that should trigger the script have their "Is Trigger" property set to true, and make sure that the object the script is on has a collider component that's set to trigger as well.

Comment: @Nysand i tried setting all coliders to triggers and it still didnt work. if it helps it is something with the colliders because when i run the code it doesnt print the debug message either

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the "Is Trigger" checkbox on the gameObject. that you have the script attached to (I would assume it to be called `Tower` or smth). You'll find that checkbox if you open up the Collider component on your `Tower` gameObject.